# React testing library's waitFor() returns null

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm testing the rejection of the submit event of my login form. If the user just submitted the form without filling up the username and password, the two error messages must show up and it should pass the test. But the result of the test shows the opposite: it shows that the username and password error messages are `null`. I tried using `setTimeout()` since the `onSubmit` event is asynchronous because of axios, but it still didn't pass the test. Is there anything wrong about the way I use the `waitFor()` utility for an asynchronous submit event?

```
it('Should render username and password error messages when both inputs are blank', () => {
    const { getByTestId, queryByTestId } = render(<Index />)

    fireEvent.submit(getByTestId('form'))

    expect(getByTestId('submit-button').disabled).toBeTruthy()

    setTimeout(async () => {
        expect(getByTestId('submit-button').disabled).toBeFalsy()

        const usernameError = await waitFor(() => queryByTestId('username-error'))
        expect(usernameError).toBeInTheDocument()

        const passwordError = await waitFor(() => queryByTestId('password-error'))
        expect(passwordError).toBeInTheDocument()
    }, 0)
})
```

[image: Test result]

Comment: Well that may mean that the element is not present. Try to print the dom to be sure

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of changes to the test that might fix this problem. Please find them in the following code as comments

```
// The first is adding async to the callback of your `it` so you don't have to use a timeout
it('Should render username and password error messages when both inputs are blank', async () => {
    const { getByTestId, findByTestId, queryByTestId } = render(<Index />)

    expect(getByTestId('submit-button').disabled).toBeTruthy()

    fireEvent.submit(getByTestId('form'))

    // Here we can use waitFor which waits until the promise triggered by the last fireEvent finishes.
    await waitFor(() => {
        expect(getByTestId('submit-button').disabled).toBeFalsy()
    })

    // Finally, you should be able to just use getByTestId to locate the elements you need, and given that the promises are resolved, they should be in the document
    expect(getByTestId('username-error')).toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(getByTestId('password-error')).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

Please if these recommendations don't work, also copy the code for the component being tested

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question as you just removed the `waitFor`. Also you should explain what you changed and why.

Comment: `findByTestId` returns an empty object. With `queryByTestId`, it would return `null`. Also, why remove `waitFor()`?

Comment: Sorry, I just updated all expect to use `getByTestId`. So the thing is, you really don't need to use those waitFor. The reason you had them in the first place, is because you were waiting for some promise to be resolved after you submitted your form. This is now replaced by the `await act(async ...`. If this is not working, please also add the code of the HTML so it's easier to find the issue.

Comment: @Victor Thanks so much for this answer! I'm wondering if you could point me to any docs on correctly using await act(..... or switching away from waitFor()? Thank you!

Comment: Hello @Sturzl. Sure thing. Please read this article by the author of react testing library https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#using-waitfor-to-wait-for-elements-that-can-be-queried-with-find. Also, the official docs are pretty good https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#waitfor